# Capturing and Preprocessing of android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

My activity is registered to android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED action and in general it works great:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivityToPpocessNfcTag"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
               android:resource="@xml/filter_nfc"
    />
</activity>
```

Problem is nature of "android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" action. Every time I'm scanning tag, I'm interested in, system prompts for application choice (some preinstall application also captures nfc tags of similar type to show some basic information). System doesn't provide "remember choice" functionality.

I understand why it is like that: there are many different kinds of nfc tags which invoke TECH_DISCOVERED action. However this action doesn't provide enough information to effectively figure out how to filter applications for each tag resulting in user having to make a choice.

Now my application without doubt can figure out which tag it can process, so is there a way to capture this intent before system prompts to choose application, so I can take actions accordingly. 
I just want get rid of this system message "choose application" and I don't want to consume all nfc tags.

Please note that "android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" is second level of NFC processing done by Android, first one is "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" which has uri and mimeType data so Android can effectively choose application to run. NFC tags I'm processing are invoking TECH_DISCOVERED action not NDEF_DISCOVERED.

Comment: On my Nexus S running ICS I am not even getting the choice to choose an application and I have a few. By default it is opening the TAG application which is a built in app. I can only use others by either starting them first and then scanning the tag or disabling the TAG application. For instance I just wrote a quick app which does nothing but has the nfc intent-filters in the manifest. I was only able to access it on tag scan when I disabled the TAG application.

Comment: Remember that Android has 3 stages of NFC processing: ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED when all data are recognized by system and mimeData URI is avaible (so application filtering kicks in), ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED when nfc technology is known but content of tag is unknown or not process by system (this doesn't have URI or mimeType so application can't be preselected) this my case, ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED when only tag was read and nothing else is recognized. Apparently you have many application registered for  ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED and none (only system one) registered for ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.

Comment: your application will take actions based upon when it receives those action from the system. I wrote a quick app earlier and I was able to receive the actions (although I had to disable the TAG application). What version you are building on?

Comment: I'm building on top of Android 4.0.3 (API level 15). To be more specific I'm trying to implement Simple Secure Pairing, everything works but I wish to remove possible application choice. Disabling tag application is not a solution.

Comment: The aim is to reduce user interaction to minimum, so if know device is scanned then Bluetooth device get connected/disconnected without any additional user click. Only when device has to be paired then UI should ask for confirmation.

Comment: Why not use the NDEF format for SSP? See http://www.nfc-forum.org/resources/AppDocs/NFCForum_AD_BTSSP_1_0.pdf That would likely solve your problem.

Comment: I do use it. Android just is not process that in case of SSP see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#well_known  RTD_HANDOVER_REQUEST and RTD_HANDOVER_SELECT falls back to ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.